# How to get the latest record rows from a two datatable based on last modified date in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Help me to write C# LINQ statement to compare Datatable 1 and Datatable 2 and both are extracted from different source and same schema in nature.

Need find the latest record based on last modified and bring all changes into one datatable or separate datatable(insert/update/delete)

Here is the scenario

**Datatable 1 : From Source X**

```
ID     Name       Age      LastModified
--------------------------------------------------
1      Raj        32       10/8/2015 2:26:28 PM
2      Shiva      27       10/9/2015 10:36:53 PM 
3      John       86       10/5/2015 7:42:25 PM
```

**Datatable 2 : From Source Y**

```
ID  Name   Age  LastModified
--------------------------------------
1   Raj    38   10/9/2015 2:26:28 PM
2   Shiva  26   10/9/2015 9:36:53 PM
3   John   86   10/5/2015 7:42:25 PM
4   Lale   56   10/12/2015 3:36:26 PM
```

**Combined and Latest DataTable**

```
ID  Name    Age   LastModified
----------------------------------------
1   Raj     38    10/9/2015 2:26:28 PM
2   Shiva   27    10/9/2015 10:36:53 PM
3   John    86    10/5/2015 7:42:25 PM 
4   Lale    56    10/12/2015 3:36:26 PM
```

Comment: Yes, you need to write it.

Answer (score 0):

Easy

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("LastModified", typeof(DateTime));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, "Raj", 38, DateTime.Parse("10/9/2015 2:26:28 PM")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, "Shiva", 27, DateTime.Parse("10/9/2015 10:36:53 PM")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {3, "John", 86, DateTime.Parse("10/5/2015 7:42:25 PM")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {4, "Lale", 56, DateTime.Parse("10/12/2015 3:36:26 PM")});

            DataRow lastest = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(x => x.Field<DateTime>("LastModified")).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Thanks Jdweng, as I mentioned in the example, we need to compare two tables from different source and select latest out of it

Comment: I assumed you joined the two tables together and just need the linq to get latest row.

Comment: That's were I'm struggling now.  :)

Comment: See left out join on following webpage. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b.  Lale is giving you an issue and the left outer join will solve the issue.

Comment: Do you have some samples on this with date validation?